# Rolling operation slow performance to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, for-loop

### Hello, I have created a code which has a very slow performance in creating a new column in a dataframe. This new column is a rolling moving average with different weights, which I obtain from a for-loop iteration , but I guess there might be a better/faster-in-performance way to do this in Python.

- The original database is similar to this (although much larger):

  ```
  idx = [np.array(['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar','Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jun', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Sep', 'Oct','Oct', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic', 'Dic',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
  data = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 9}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 8}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 9}]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['x'])
  df.index.names=['date','type']
  ```

And it looks like this:

```
           x
date type
Jan  A     1
     B     5
Feb  B     3
Mar  A     2
     B     7
     C     3
Apr  A     1
     B     6
May  B     3
Jun  A     5
     B     2
     C     3
Jul  A     1
Aug  B     9
     C     3
Sep  A     2
     B     7
Oct  C     3
     A     6
     B     8
Nov  A     2
Dic  B     7
     C     9
```

- My goal is to improve the following code to create a new column in the dataframe (rolling moving average with different weights). My code is:

  ```
  df=df.reset_index()
  df['rolling']=0
  for j in df['type'].unique():
      list_1=list(df['x'][df['type']==j])
      cumsum = [0]
      list_2=list(df['x'][df['type']==j].index)
      z=[]
      for i, h in enumerate(list_1, 1):
          if i>=4:
            cumsum.append(0.2*list_1[i-4]+0.3*list_1[i-3]+0.5*list_1[i-2])
          else:
            cumsum.append('NaN')
          cumsum.pop(0)
          z.append(cumsum[0])
      df['rolling'][list_2]=z
  ```

And it looks like this:

```
   date type  x rolling
0   Jan    A  1     NaN
1   Jan    B  5     NaN
2   Feb    B  3     NaN
3   Mar    A  2     NaN
4   Mar    B  7     NaN
5   Mar    C  3     NaN
6   Apr    A  1     NaN
7   Apr    B  6     5.4
8   May    B  3     5.7
9   Jun    A  5     1.3
10  Jun    B  2     4.7
11  Jun    C  3     NaN
12  Jul    A  1     3.2
13  Aug    B  9     3.1
14  Aug    C  3     NaN
15  Sep    A  2     2.2
16  Sep    B  7     5.7
17  Oct    C  3       3
18  Oct    A  6     2.3
19  Oct    B  8     6.6
20  Nov    A  2     3.8
21  Dic    B  7     7.9
22  Dic    C  9       3
```

** If you have a code that has a better performance than mine, it would be interesting to know how much faster it is. If you think your code is better, but you don't know how much faster it is, post it anyways because I will realize with a larger dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this to see if this speed up your code any:

```
idx = [np.array(['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar','Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jun', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Sep', 'Oct','Oct', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic', 'Dic',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
data = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 9}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 8}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['x'])
df.index.names=['date','type']

df['rolling'] = df.groupby('type')['x'].rolling(4).apply(lambda x: x[-4]*.2 + x[-3]*.3 + x[-2]*.5, raw=True)\
                  .reset_index(level=2, drop=True).swaplevel(0,1)

df
```

Output:

```
           x  rolling
date type            
Jan  A     1      NaN
     B     5      NaN
Feb  B     3      NaN
Mar  A     2      NaN
     B     7      NaN
     C     3      NaN
Apr  A     1      NaN
     B     6      5.4
May  B     3      5.7
Jun  A     5      1.3
     B     2      4.7
     C     3      NaN
Jul  A     1      3.2
Aug  B     9      3.1
     C     3      NaN
Sep  A     2      2.2
     B     7      5.7
Oct  C     3      3.0
     A     6      2.3
     B     8      6.6
Nov  A     2      3.8
Dic  B     7      7.9
     C     9      3.0
```

Timings....

Your code:

324 ms ± 1.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

This code:

12.6 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: Thank you Scott. I am really surprised of how much faster an elegant code in Pandas can be compared with my old school style of coding. However I am still lost using indexes and multindixes with Pandas and It would be very useful if you can help with this 4 examples (see question below):https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070398/replace-iterations-by-elegant-pandas-code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `numpy` version. It gives a healthy (68x on the small example) speedup. Since it uses linear correlation this factor should become even larger if your real window is longer than 3 because `correlate` will switch to more efficient fft based method.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal

idx = [np.array(['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar','Apr', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jun', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Sep', 'Oct','Oct', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic', 'Dic',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
data = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 9}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 8}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['x'])
df.index.names=['date','type']
df = df.reset_index()

weights = np.array((0.2,0.3,0.5))

def running_avg():
    if 'running' in df.columns:
        del df['running']
    n = len(weights)

    tp, x = df['type'].values, df['x'].values
    sidx = np.argsort(tp, kind='stable') 

    stp = tp[sidx]
    bnds = np.where(stp[1:] != stp[:-1])[0] + 1

    running = np.empty(sidx.shape)
    for bit in np.split(sidx, bnds):
        running[bit[:n]] = np.nan
        if len(bit) > n:
            running[bit[n:]] = signal.correlate(x[bit[:-1]], weights, 'valid', 'auto')
    df['running'] = running

def running_OP():
    df['rolling']=0
    for j in df['type'].unique():
        list_1=list(df['x'][df['type']==j])
        cumsum = [0]
        list_2=list(df['x'][df['type']==j].index)
        z=[]
        for i, h in enumerate(list_1, 1):
            if i>=4:
              cumsum.append(0.2*list_1[i-4]+0.3*list_1[i-3]+0.5*list_1[i-2])
            else:
              cumsum.append('NaN')
            cumsum.pop(0)
            z.append(cumsum[0])
        df['rolling'][list_2]=z

from timeit import repeat

T0 = np.array(repeat(running_OP, repeat=7, number=10))*100
print(f'\nOP: {T0.mean():.3f} ± {T0.std():.3f} ms')
T1 = np.array(repeat(running_avg, repeat=7, number=100))*10000
print(f'pp {T1.mean():.3f} ± {T1.std():.3f} \N{GREEK SMALL LETTER MU}s')

print("\nresults are " + ["different", "equal"][((np.isnan(df['running']) & np.isnan(df['rolling'].astype(float))) | (df['running'] == df['rolling'])).all()])
print(f'speedup roughly {T0.mean()/T1.mean()*1000:.0f}\N{MULTIPLICATION X}')
```

Sample run:

```
OP: 62.500 ± 0.473 ms
pp 903.769 ± 11.491 μs

results are equal
speedup roughly 69✕
```