# Replace Iterations by elegant Pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to change my old school codes for the elegant/fast Pandas codes, such as the one of this previous question:

[Rolling operation slow performance to create a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064457/rolling-operation-slow-performance-to-create-a-new-column/56065415#56065415)

I have 4 different codes that I would like to improve in performance with an elegant and fast code using Pandas.

### 1) Mean by date for all types:

The original dataframe (df) is similar to this (although much larger):

```
idx = [np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Apr-18', 'Apr-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
data = [{'x': 1}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 5}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3},{'x': 1}, {'x': 9}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 6}, {'x': 8}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 7}, {'x': 9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['x'])
df.index.names=['date','type']
df=df.reset_index()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%b-%y')
df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
```

And it looks like this:

```
                 x
date       type
2018-01-01 A     1
           B     5
2018-02-01 B     3
2018-03-01 A     2
           B     7
           C     3
2018-04-01 A     1
           B     6
2018-05-01 B     3
2018-06-01 A     5
           B     2
           C     3
2018-07-01 A     1
2018-08-01 B     9
           C     3
2018-09-01 A     2
           B     7
2018-10-01 C     3
           A     6
           B     8
2018-11-01 A     2
2018-12-01 B     7
           C     9
```

My goal is to improve this slow for-loop code. Below my code:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['y']=0
for j in df['date'].unique():
    list_1=list(df['type'][df['date']==j].index)
    df['y'][list_1]=np.mean(df['x'][df['date']==j])
```

The result looks like this:

```
         date type  x         y
0  2018-01-01    A  1  3.000000
1  2018-01-01    B  5  3.000000
2  2018-02-01    B  3  3.000000
3  2018-03-01    A  2  4.000000
4  2018-03-01    B  7  4.000000
5  2018-03-01    C  3  4.000000
6  2018-04-01    A  1  3.500000
7  2018-04-01    B  6  3.500000
8  2018-05-01    B  3  3.000000
9  2018-06-01    A  5  3.333333
10 2018-06-01    B  2  3.333333
11 2018-06-01    C  3  3.333333
12 2018-07-01    A  1  1.000000
13 2018-08-01    B  9  6.000000
14 2018-08-01    C  3  6.000000
15 2018-09-01    A  2  4.500000
16 2018-09-01    B  7  4.500000
17 2018-10-01    C  3  5.666667
18 2018-10-01    A  6  5.666667
19 2018-10-01    B  8  5.666667
20 2018-11-01    A  2  2.000000
21 2018-12-01    B  7  8.000000
22 2018-12-01    C  9  8.000000
```

** I tried the following Pandas code, but it doesn't work (I still need to see more examples to figure out how it works):

```
df['y'] = df.groupby('date')['x'].mean().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).swaplevel(0,1)
```

### 2) Observations by date for all types (uses the same dataframe (df)):

My goal is to measure the number of types for every date.

My slow code is:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['y']=0
for j in df['date'].unique():
    list_1=list(df['type'][df['date']==j].index)
    df['y'][list_1]=len(df['type'][df['date']==j])
```

The result looks like this:

```
         date type  x  y
0  2018-01-01    A  1  2
1  2018-01-01    B  5  2
2  2018-02-01    B  3  1
3  2018-03-01    A  2  3
4  2018-03-01    B  7  3
5  2018-03-01    C  3  3
6  2018-04-01    A  1  2
7  2018-04-01    B  6  2
8  2018-05-01    B  3  1
9  2018-06-01    A  5  3
10 2018-06-01    B  2  3
11 2018-06-01    C  3  3
12 2018-07-01    A  1  1
13 2018-08-01    B  9  2
14 2018-08-01    C  3  2
15 2018-09-01    A  2  2
16 2018-09-01    B  7  2
17 2018-10-01    C  3  3
18 2018-10-01    A  6  3
19 2018-10-01    B  8  3
20 2018-11-01    A  2  1
21 2018-12-01    B  7  2
22 2018-12-01    C  9  2
```

### 3) Observations by date for 'A' type (uses the same dataframe (df)):

My goal is to measure the number of type A for every date.

My slow code is the following:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['z']=0
df['y']=0

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['type']=='A':
        df['z'][index]=1
    else:
        df['z'][index]=0

for j in df['date'].unique():
    list_1=list(df['type'][df['date']==j].index)
    df['y'][list_1]=sum(df['z'][df['date']==j])

del df['z']
```

And it looks like this:

```
         date type  x  y
0  2018-01-01    A  1  1
1  2018-01-01    B  5  1
2  2018-02-01    B  3  0
3  2018-03-01    A  2  1
4  2018-03-01    B  7  1
5  2018-03-01    C  3  1
6  2018-04-01    A  1  1
7  2018-04-01    B  6  1
8  2018-05-01    B  3  0
9  2018-06-01    A  5  1
10 2018-06-01    B  2  1
11 2018-06-01    C  3  1
12 2018-07-01    A  1  1
13 2018-08-01    B  9  0
14 2018-08-01    C  3  0
15 2018-09-01    A  2  1
16 2018-09-01    B  7  1
17 2018-10-01    C  3  1
18 2018-10-01    A  6  1
19 2018-10-01    B  8  1
20 2018-11-01    A  2  1
21 2018-12-01    B  7  0
22 2018-12-01    C  9  0
```

### 4) Observations for 'A' type for which its z value = 1:

Please use the following dataframe (df1):

```
idx = [np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Apr-18', 'Apr-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
data = [{'x': 10, 'z': 1}, {'x': 50, 'z': 0}, {'x': 30, 'z': 0}, {'x': 20, 'z': 0}, {'x': 70, 'z': 1}, {'x': 30, 'z': 1},{'x': 10, 'z': 1}, {'x': 60, 'z': 0}, {'x': 30, 'z': 0}, {'x': 50, 'z': 1}, {'x': 20, 'z': 0}, {'x': 30, 'z': 1},{'x': 10, 'z': 0}, {'x': 90, 'z': 1}, {'x': 30, 'z': 1}, {'x': 20, 'z': 1}, {'x': 70, 'z': 0}, {'x': 30, 'z': 0}, {'x': 60, 'z': 1}, {'x': 80, 'z': 1}, {'x': 20, 'z': 0}, {'x': 70, 'z': 0}, {'x': 90, 'z': 1}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['x','z'])
df1.index.names=['date','type']
df1=df1.reset_index()
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'],format = '%b-%y')
df1=df1.set_index(['date','type'])
```

This dataframe (df1) looks like this:

```
                  x  z
date       type
2018-01-01 A     10  1
           B     50  0
2018-02-01 B     30  0
2018-03-01 A     20  0
           B     70  1
           C     30  1
2018-04-01 A     10  1
           B     60  0
2018-05-01 B     30  0
2018-06-01 A     50  1
           B     20  0
           C     30  1
2018-07-01 A     10  0
2018-08-01 B     90  1
           C     30  1
2018-09-01 A     20  1
           B     70  0
2018-10-01 C     30  0
           A     60  1
           B     80  1
2018-11-01 A     20  0
2018-12-01 B     70  0
           C     90  1
```

My slow code is:

```
df1=df1.reset_index()
df1['h']=0
df1['k']=0
df1['y']=0

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['type']=='A':
        df1['h'][index]=1
    else:
        df1['h'][index]=0

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['z']==1 and row['h']==1:
        df1['k'][index]=1
    else:
        df1['k'][index]=0   

for j in df1['date'].unique():
    list_1=list(df1['type'][df1['date']==j].index)
    df1['y'][list_1]=sum(df1['k'][df1['date']==j])

del df1['h']
del df1['k']
```

And it looks like this:

```
         date type   x  z  y
0  2018-01-01    A  10  1  1
1  2018-01-01    B  50  0  1
2  2018-02-01    B  30  0  0
3  2018-03-01    A  20  0  0
4  2018-03-01    B  70  1  0
5  2018-03-01    C  30  1  0
6  2018-04-01    A  10  1  1
7  2018-04-01    B  60  0  1
8  2018-05-01    B  30  0  0
9  2018-06-01    A  50  1  1
10 2018-06-01    B  20  0  1
11 2018-06-01    C  30  1  1
12 2018-07-01    A  10  0  0
13 2018-08-01    B  90  1  0
14 2018-08-01    C  30  1  0
15 2018-09-01    A  20  1  1
16 2018-09-01    B  70  0  1
17 2018-10-01    C  30  0  1
18 2018-10-01    A  60  1  1
19 2018-10-01    B  80  1  1
20 2018-11-01    A  20  0  0
21 2018-12-01    B  70  0  0
22 2018-12-01    C  90  1  0
```

Although the question seems long I know that the answers with Pandas can be in a few lines of code. If you can let me know how much faster are your codes than mine it would be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `groupby` + `transform`. Here the `.transform` is key as it broadcasts the result back to all rows in the original DataFrame that belong to that group.

For the first we can transform on `x`, simply.

For the unique types, it's faster to bring it to a column than it is to deal with the index, so `assign` a column and calculate the # of unique values within group.

For the final two conditions, you can create a Boolean column to see if that row satisfies the condition, which you sum within groups.

```
#1 Get the mean of `x` by date
df['x_avg'] = df.groupby('date').x.transform('mean')

#2 Get the # of unique types. 
df['N'] = (df.assign(TYPE = df.index.get_level_values('type'))
             .groupby('date').TYPE.transform('nunique'))

#3 Get the number of Type == A within a group
df['num_A']  = (df.assign(eqA = (df.index.get_level_values('type') == 'A'))
                  .groupby('date').eqA.transform(sum).astype(int))

#4 Really just a slight extension of 3
df1['cond_4']  = (df1.assign(to_sum = ((df1.index.get_level_values('type') == 'A')
                                       &  (df1.z == 1)).astype(int))
                     .groupby('date').to_sum.transform(sum))
```

#### Output `df`:

```
                 x  num_A     x_avg  N
date       type                       
2018-01-01 A     1      1  3.000000  2
           B     5      1  3.000000  2
2018-02-01 B     3      0  3.000000  1
2018-03-01 A     2      1  4.000000  3
           B     7      1  4.000000  3
           C     3      1  4.000000  3
2018-04-01 A     1      1  3.500000  2
           B     6      1  3.500000  2
2018-05-01 B     3      0  3.000000  1
2018-06-01 A     5      1  3.333333  3
           B     2      1  3.333333  3
           C     3      1  3.333333  3
2018-07-01 A     1      1  1.000000  1
2018-08-01 B     9      0  6.000000  2
           C     3      0  6.000000  2
2018-09-01 A     2      1  4.500000  2
           B     7      1  4.500000  2
2018-10-01 C     3      1  5.666667  3
           A     6      1  5.666667  3
           B     8      1  5.666667  3
2018-11-01 A     2      1  2.000000  1
2018-12-01 B     7      0  8.000000  2
           C     9      0  8.000000  2
```

Comment: Thank you Alloz. I am really impressed with the coding power of Pandas.I need to start figuring out how this work. This examples and answer are very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For first case, you can try below:

`df['y'] = df.groupby('date')['x'].transform(np.mean)`

For last case:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1['h'] = np.where(df1.reset_index()['type'] == 'A', 1, 0)
df1['k'] = np.where((df1.h == 1) & (df1.z == 1), 1, 0)
df1.y = df1.groupby('date')['k'].transform(np.sum)
del df1['h']
del df1['k']
```